# Kotlin Retrofit not returning json object data from an Api call

Tags: android, rest, kotlin

I'm creating an Kotlin Android mobile application and need to call a Rest Api to bring customer data to the app.  I'm using Retrofit to attempt this function.

I have a POST interface that passes a body of a sessionKey to a Rest Api endpoint.

The call to the Api is succesful but my response is empty of any data that i'm expecting back.  The Api consits of many Objects containing data.  Example below of the Json that is returned when making the Post request via Postman;

```
{
 "OrderingOrderInfoResponseStruct": {
"deliveryAddresses": {
  "OrderingDeliveryAddressStruct": [
    {
      "deliveryAddressNo": 5800009,
      "deliveryAddressName": "BASILDON & THURROCK NHS",
      "pointsOfService": {
        "OrderingPointOfServiceStruct": [
          {
            "pointOfServiceNo": 1,
            "pointOfServiceName": "A & E",
            "pointOfServiceDescription": "A & E 12",
            "pointOfServiceOrderingGroupNo": "580-1",
            "orders": {
              "OrderingOrderStruct": [
                {
                  "orderType": "inventory",
                  "orderDate": "2023-07-07",
                  "deliveryDate": "2023-07-07",
                  "orderStatus": 0,
                  "articles": {
                    "OrderingArticleStruct": [
                      {
                        "articleNo": 109842,
                        "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS TOP SHEET S",
                        "articleSize": "",
                        "articleTargetQty": 385,
                        "articleMinQty": 0,
                        "articleMaxQty": 0,
                        "articleIntervalQty": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "articleNo": 103046,
                        "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS PILLOWCASE",
                        "articleSize": "",
                        "articleTargetQty": 15,
                        "articleMinQty": 0,
                        "articleMaxQty": 0,
                        "articleIntervalQty": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "articleNo": 106856,
                        "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS BATH TOWEL",
                        "articleSize": "",
                        "articleTargetQty": 24,
                        "articleMinQty": 0,
                        "articleMaxQty": 0,
                        "articleIntervalQty": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "articleNo": 106482,
                        "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS BLANKET THERMAL BLUE",
                        "articleSize": "",
                        "articleTargetQty": 130,
                        "articleMinQty": 0,
                        "articleMaxQty": 0,
                        "articleIntervalQty": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "articleNo": 106812,
                        "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS PATIENT MODESTY GOWN",
                        "articleSize": "",
                        "articleTargetQty": 65,
                        "articleMinQty": 0,
                        "articleMaxQty": 0,
                        "articleIntervalQty": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "articleNo": 106420,
                        "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS PLASTIC BAGS WHITE",
                        "articleSize": "",
                        "articleTargetQty": 75,
                        "articleMinQty": 0,
                        "articleMaxQty": 0,
                        "articleIntervalQty": 0
                      },
                      {
                        "articleNo": 106458,
                        "articleDescription": "ESSENTIALS BAGS WATER SOLUBLE",
                        "articleSize": "",
                        "articleTargetQty": 25,
                        "articleMinQty": 0,
                        "articleMaxQty": 0,
                        "articleIntervalQty": 0
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
},
"orderingGroups": {
  "OrderingOrderingGroupStruct": [
    {
      "orderingGroupNo": "580-1",
      "orderingGroupDescription": "58000009 BASILDON OPD 1"
    },
    {
      "orderingGroupNo": "580-2",
      "orderingGroupDescription": "58000009 BASILDON OPD 2"
    },
    {
      "orderingGroupNo": "580-3",
      "orderingGroupDescription": "58000009 BASILDON OPD 3"
    },
    {
      "orderingGroupNo": "580-4",
      "orderingGroupDescription": "ROYALFREE TOWER BLOCK"
    },
    {
      "orderingGroupNo": "580-5",
      "orderingGroupDescription": "5800024 ROYAL FREE OPD 2"
    },
    {
      "orderingGroupNo": "580-6",
      "orderingGroupDescription": "5800024 ROYAL FREE OPD 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

The call to the Api from the app is successful, i get a 200 status and OK message but no data.
[image]

I have several data classes, all generated using the Json from the Api and the Kotlin data class from JSON file Android studio plugin.  I've also tried using Pojo to generate the relevant model classes.

Here is my interface and retrofit instance;

```
interface OrderInfoApiService1 {
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
@POST("OrderInfo")
suspend fun getOrderInfo(@Body orderInfoRequest: OrderingRequest): Response<SolServices>
}

suspend fun fetchOrderInfo(orderInfoRequest: OrderingRequest) {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())// MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(clientTime)
        .build()

    val retrofitService = retrofit.create(OrderInfoApiService1::class.java)
```

I get no message relating to no data in the Logcat.

Can anyone think of anything i could try and anything that's really obvious that i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the return data without wrapping it in Response<*>

```
interface OrderInfoApiService1 {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @POST("OrderInfo")
    suspend fun getOrderInfo(@Body orderInfoRequest: OrderingRequest): SolServices
}
```

It will work because your function is `suspend` function and you don't need to wrap the response.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I've made the change and it's still the same outcome. No data returned.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a Http logger and noticed that the data is coming in on that response, so my issue must be elsewhere.

I have closed this question and Asked another.

Thank you.